# How to set default value to field using JS DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JS DataTables plugin for rendering my tables, and in some rows I have NULL values in specific column:

My dataset looks like this, and table is generated and rendered serverside.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HostingID] => 1
            [UserID] => 1
            [HostingDomain] => reasda.hrt
            [Coupon] => coupon1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HostingID] => 2
            [UserID] => 1
            [HostingDomain] => asdasd.hr
            [Coupon] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [HostingID] => 3
            [UserID] => 1
            [HostingDomain] => asdasds-hre
            [Coupon] => 
        )
)
```

My JS is simple as it can be, because some default settings are initialized in included file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function ()
    {
        var table = jQuery('#tableActiveHostingServicesList').removeClass('hidden').DataTable( );

        table.draw();
        jQuery('#tableLoading').addClass('hidden');
    });
</script>
```

And this is my view part:

```
<table id="tableActiveHostingServicesList" class="table table-list hidden">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First column</th>
                        <th>Second column</th>
                        <th>Third column</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {foreach from=$activeservices item=activeservice}
                        <tr>

                            <td class="text-center">{$activeservice.HostingDomain}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{$activeservice.Coupon}</span></td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
                                    Reedem!
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {/foreach}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to loop through your dataset in PHP and set a default value before rendering the data in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property to define what will be displayed. change the initialisation code so that use render to check for null before showing the column value.  In this example, a hypen is shown if the column value is null:

```
var table = jQuery('#tableActiveHostingServicesList').removeClass('hidden').DataTable({
    'columns': [
     {
          // HostingID
          'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
               if(full[0] != null){
                   return full[0];
                }else{
                   return '-';
                }
            },
          // UserID
          'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
               if(full[1] != null){
                   return full[1];
                }else{
                   return '-';
                }
            },
            ... etc
});
```